# simple way to convert any audio file to GSM based NAudio

Tags: c#, .net-core, naudio

is there a simple way do to it?

platform is NETCore and any other simple way based NETCore is good.

something like :

```
public static bool convertToGSM(string sourcePath, string destPath)
{
    using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(sourcePath))
    {
        var gsm = new WaveFormat(8000, 8, 1);
        WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(destPath, gsm);
        //here is missing a few steps...?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple example (F#) [here: https://markheath.net/post/wav-to-gsm-naudio-fsharp](https://markheath.net/post/wav-to-gsm-naudio-fsharp)

```
let convertToGsm (input:string) output =
    use reader = new WaveFileReader(input)
    let targetFormat = new Gsm610WaveFormat()
    use converter = new WaveFormatConversionStream(targetFormat, reader)
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(output, converter)

convertToGsm "pcm.wav" "gsm.wav"
```